# Powershell standalone DNS server

Tags: c#, powershell, dns

I am can try to convert dns server example in C# to powershell, but my code don't work. I am use [ARSoft.Tools.Net.dll](https://docs.ar-soft.de/arsoft.tools.net/#DNS%20Server.html)
This is worked code in c#:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (DnsServer server = new DnsServer(10, 10))
        {
            server.QueryReceived += OnQueryReceived;

            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop server");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static void OnQueryReceived(object sender, QueryReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        DnsMessage query = e.Query as DnsMessage;

        query.IsQuery = false;

        // check for valid query
        if ((query != null)
            && (query.Questions.Count == 1)
            && (query.Questions[0].RecordType == RecordType.Txt)
            && (query.Questions[0].Name.Equals("example.com", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
        {
            query.ReturnCode = ReturnCode.NoError;
            query.AnswerRecords.Add(new TxtRecord("example.com", 3600, "Hello world"));
        }
        else
        {
            query.ReturnCode = ReturnCode.ServerFailure;
        }

        // set the response
        e.Response = query;
    }
}
```

And my code in powershell that not work:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\ARSoft.Tools.Net.dll")
$OnQueryReceived = {
    [ARSoft.Tools.Net.Dns.DnsMessage]$query = $event.SourceArgs.Query
    $query.IsQuery = $false;
    $query.ReturnCode = [ARSoft.Tools.Net.Dns.ReturnCode]::NoError
    $query.AnswerRecords.Add((new-object ARSoft.Tools.Net.Dns.TxtRecord("example.com", 3600, "Hello world")))    
    $event.SourceArgs.Response = $query
}

$server = New-Object ARSoft.Tools.Net.Dns.DnsServer(10,10)

Register-ObjectEvent -inputObject $server -eventName "QueryReceived" -Action $OnQueryReceived
$server.Start()
```

Where is my error?

Comment: Please add the exact error you are getting!

Comment: I am not have any response from "nslookup google.com 127.0.0.1" when run powershell code, but its work when i am compile c# code.

Comment: @jobsys have you tried declaring the arguments as parameters inside the `$OnQueryReceived` block? `param($sender,$event)`

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen I think $event passed to $OnQueryReceived automatically, because we have declared $event in my script. Now i am try to insert param($sender,$event) to my script, and nothing change($sender not not available). Please help to solve my problem.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I spent on it is 3 days. I can not do without your expert level. Nowhere in the network can not find your email. Can you help me solve the problem?

Comment: @jobsys There's a reason my email is nowhere to be found ;) Join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89059/powershell-arsoft-dns-event-handling and I'll try to help you troubleshoot it